# Downscaling images increases memory consumption?

Tags: python, image, storage

I have a large image dataset that I am trying to use in Google Colab. But, the .zip file is too large. So, I am downscaling the images to reduce the memory usage. The code I'm using is:

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img = cv2.resize(img, (int(img.shape[1] * 0.75), int(img.shape[0] * 0.75)))
cv2.imwrite(img_save_path, img)
```

However, after doing this for ~100k images, it seems that the original images take up almost 3 Gb less than the downscaled images. I don't understand why this is happening. I've double checked the image sizes to confirm that they are getting reduced in size. It seems very counter-intuitive that reducing the image size increases the memory consumed.

Comment: what about compression?

Comment: Are you saving your files to disk? If yes please add code which is responsible for that action

Comment: I'm saving the images using cv2.imwrite, and all images are .jpg images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the JPEG quality, or compression. Basically, `imwrite()` in **OpenCV** writes with a default JPEG quality of 95 if you don't tell it otherwise. If your original images were lower in quality, the file size will increase when you write them with **OpenCV**.

Let's look in more detail. Create a random image with **ImageMagick** with quality 75:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc: +noise random -quality 75 image.jpg
```

[image]

The file size is 176kB, and we can check the quality with **ImageMagick**

```
identify -verbose image.jpg | grep Quality
Quality: 75
```

Or, maybe more simply with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -JPEGQualityEstimate image.jpg
JPEG Quality Estimate           : 75
```

Now load the image into OpenCV and write 3 different ways:

```
import cv2

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Write carelessly using default parameters
cv2.imwrite('default.jpg',im)

# Write with quality 60 and 80
cv2.imwrite('Q60.jpg',im,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 60])
cv2.imwrite('Q80.jpg',im,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 80])
```

And the results are clear:

```
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   347005  4 Sep 10:38 default.jpg
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   138115  4 Sep 10:38 Q60.jpg
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   190183  4 Sep 10:38 Q80.jpg
```

When written with default settings, the file has ballooned from 176kB to 347kB. When written with quality 60 or 80 the file size is much smaller.